# Initial question marked down and voted to close, after revising reopened. Should it be marked back up?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question recently, Initially I thought that I tried to explain things clearly. But it turned out it was getting marked down for not being clear, it was put on hold and then voted to close. I then however revised the question and provided a little more clarity and then the question was voted to reopen.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629887/how-to-round-value-to-nearest-integer)

If this happens, I'm assuming it met community standards? should the question be marked back up?

Comment: Eventually, it will. Or not. But you got a solution worth... how much?

Comment: If a question has been downvoted by a user commenting/providing answers. Shouldn't they have the option to upvote on their intial downvote?

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215334/244519

Comment: They have, provided they come back and decidto reverse the vote. But how do you know who voted? Not possible.

Comment: I don't want to know who voted, i just checked the link provided by @cVplZ there is a feature request to notify users who vote on questions if they are revised http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c

Comment: It is possible that after editing, your quesiton is applicable for reopening but is nontheless a bad question. E.g. you could ask a question that gets closed because you don't provide a reproducable example; you subsequently edit it to add an example and the example demonstrates you just didn't read the docs. And while IMO these questions shouldn't be reopenend in the first place, it happens often enough - just like useless edits to low-level crap questions are approved all the time.

Answer (score 5):

> should the question be marked back up?

There is no mechanism by which a question that is reopened somehow gets old downvotes annulled.

If earlier downvoters revisit your question and find that it meets their standards, they can undo their downvotes, and they can upvote but they are not required to do so.

The people who voted to reopen are not required to upvote but may do so if they wish. People who see your question after it was reopened may chose to upvote. Or they may chose to downvote if they find that the reopened question is not up to their standards.